# Spark / Scala how to write a complex query that iterates through a dataframe and adds a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe (let's call it `Dataframe 1`) that has the following rows:

```
+----------+------------+----------+
|COLLECTION|START_DAY_ID|END_DAY_ID|
+----------+------------+----------+
|  HIVER 19|    20190602|  20191130|
|    ETE 19|    20181202|  20190601|
+----------+------------+----------+
```

I have a function that takes as input: `start_date` and `end_date` and returns an array of the dates that are ranked between start_date and end_date.

This is the function's signature:

```
def days_in_range(start_day: String, end_day: String, df_calendar: DataFrame): Array[String]
```

What I need to perform is to go through each row of Dataframe 1 , get the start_date and the end_date from the row and then add a new value to a new column (days in between) that contains the array of days between start_date and end_date by calling the function.

The result should look like this:

```
+------------+-----------------------+
| COLLECTION |                  days |
+------------+-----------------------+
|   ETE 2019 |[20191226,20191225,...]|
| HIVER 2019 |[20190626,20190825,...]|
+------------+-----------------------+
```

I tried couple of things like WithColumn / map and reduce / udf functions but the main problem was that for example inside the map function I was using another dataframe which caused a nullpointer exception ( same problem with udf).

Any help on how to solve this will be much appreciated.

Comment: don't use images but instead copy the text format

Comment: why dii you mention dataframe2 for? I think its not needed to be mentioned

Comment: You're right I already used Dataframe2 while implementing the function

Comment: Can you show the code that didn't work? Also, are you required to use the function? It strikes me that this is implementable as a `join` followed by `groupBy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `udf` function as below for generating the *array of string dates* in between `START_DAY_ID` and `END_DAY_ID` columns

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def days_in_range = udf((start_day: String, diff:Int)=>{
  val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")
  val calStart = Calendar.getInstance
  val startDate = calStart.setTime(format.parse(start_day))
  val listBuffer = new ListBuffer[String]
  for(day <- 1 until diff) {
    calStart.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
    listBuffer.append(format.format(calStart.getTime))
  }
  listBuffer
})
```

`diff` *Integer* is derived using `dateDiff` *inbuilt function* while calling the `udf` function as

```
df1.select(col("COLLECTION"), days_in_range(col("START_DAY_ID"), datediff(to_date(col("END_DAY_ID"), "yyyyMMdd"), to_date(col("START_DAY_ID"), "yyyyMMdd"))).as("days"))
  .show()
```

which should give you

```
+----------+--------------------+
|COLLECTION|                days|
+----------+--------------------+
|  HIVER_19|[20190903, 201909...|
|    ETE_19|[20181203, 201812...|
+----------+--------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: This helps a lot. Thank you !

Comment: my pleasure @HelaChikhaoui :) great to hear that the answer helped